# how do i get points to show in my plotly go.scatter3d()

Tags: plotly

this is the code for my scatterplot i want data points to show
[image]

```
    plot = [go.Scatter3d(x = x,
                y = y,
                z = z,
                mode = 'markers',
                text = df['CHAUFFEUR'],
                textposition='bottom center',
                hoverinfo = 'text',
                marker=dict(size=5,opacity=0.8,symbol="circle",color='Aqua'))]

    layout = go.Layout(title='Drivers')
    fig = go.Figure(data=plot, layout=layout)
    plt.iplot(fig)
    dcc.Input(placeholder='Enter a value...',type='text',value='')
```

Comment: Can you add your values for `x`, `y` and `z`. If you provide a [MCVE] you hopefully should get an answer soon.